# Dynamic Label in Java

Tags: java, netbeans, dynamic, label

I want to create an application when I click on a button a label will created and added in a JPanel. How can achieve that.

If I more describe the application that I am planing to do. Think of a contacts application, when we create a add new contact button a new contact will added to the contacts list, Like that way I want to dynamically add labels to a panel.

Comment: Your question is fairly open-ended. Have you tried something so far?

Comment: ya i have tried like this way

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
     SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
         jPanel1.add(new JLabel("Bla"));
         jPanel1.validate();
         jPanel1.repaint();
     });